# Fire functions consecutively with delay between each

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

I have a bunch of different functions in a class like this :

```
var helper = {    

     h1 : function(){
           //does  stuff        
    },

     h2 : function(){   
         //does  stuff
    },

    ...

}
```

and I can execute what I need with something like :

```
$('#helper').click(function(){
    helper.h4();
 // then delay then execute h5(), delay h6(), etc... 
     });
```

How could I have it so the functions execute consecutively with a defined `delay` between each.  I am not sure how I could do this but I suspect I need to use  `queue`, `dequeue`, and `delay` or something with `setTimeout` ?

Comment: You should read this article to understand timing in JavaScript. It isn't as logical as it may seem: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Are you trying to get the two fadein's in each function to run consecutively, or call each function (h1, h2, h3) consecutively?

Comment: i guess a simple setTimeout in the middle will stall everything (but I might be wrong)

Comment: @BryanDowning , Thanks.  That looks like a great read.

Comment: @Lazerblade, the latter.

Comment: @ajax333221—yes, you're wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
setTimeout(helper.h4, 0);
setTimeout(helper.h5, 1000);
setTimeout(helper.h6, 2000);
…
```

Note that each timeout will be started immediately, so the delay is from the same instant (more or less). You might want to capture the returned values from the calls so you can cancel timeouts that haven't been called yet for whatever reason.

Comment: This would work, if each function took the same amount of time to execute. You may be better off chaining them together in your initial helper definition, using callbacks to call the next one, assuming you need to run them in the same order each time.

Comment: Thank you both.  I do not know that I want each function to take the same amount of time, I was hoping for more flexibility. And I was hoping to be able to use this class for other things and if I put callbacks in it as Lazerblade suggests then I will not be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks RobG, I will play with this idea.  Can you please elaborate on how I capture the returned values?  I do want to have a cancel button that kills the function.

Comment: When you call [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), it returns a reference to the timeout, e.g. `var ref = setTimeout(...);`. You can cancel it using `clearTimeout(ref);`. Store the references in a array or object and call [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) for the ones you want to stop.